# I am now developing an Android app with Kotlin,but it occurred an error:CompilationException: Couldn't inline method call 'readText' into

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio-2.3

I'm now studying kotlin,but when I tried to use it for network request,the AndroidStudio threw an exception below with my code.

```
public class CustomRequest(val city_code:String){
    fun execute():ForecastResult{
        val url = URL(SERVER+PARAM)
        val forecastResStr = url.readText()
        Log.e("MyApplication",forecastResStr)
        return JSON.parseObject(forecastResStr,ForecastResult::class.java)
    }

}
```

Now I can't Compile with my app,please help.Thanks.

the exception is here:

```
Error:(18, 59) org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't inline method call 'readText' into
    fun execute():DataResult{
            val resultStr = URL (COMPLETE_URL+city_code).readText()
            return JSON.parseObject(resultStr,SomeClass::class.java)
        }

    cause: Not generated
    Cause: List has more than one element.
    File being compiled and position: (18,59) in D:/WorkSpaces/asWorkSpace/xxx/xxx/x/DataResult.kt
    PsiElement: readText()
    The root cause was thrown at: _Collections.kt:473
```

Comment: clean and rebuild

Comment: Well, it is an internal error, looks like a bug

Comment: which kotlin version?

Comment: kotlin version is 1.2.0,and androidStudio is 2.3.3